# How to display list items using index in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: java, javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement to display the list of items in angular with each row having only 2 items. Suppose there are 5 items in the list, the output should be 3 rows with first 2 rows with 2 columns and last row with one column.

```html
<div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">{{result[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">{{result[$index + 1]}}</div>
</div>
```

Above is the code, this code works fine when the result is a list of items. But when the result is a list of objects it does not print. Example, if result object has birthDate or Id property how do i display those? `{{result.birthDate}}` prints the correct value but how do I print the **index + 1 value** ? I tried `{{result[$index + 1].birthDate}}` or `{{result.birthDate[$index + 1]}}` does not work.
The below code does not work but, i need something like this,

```html
<div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">{{result[$index].birthDate}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">{{result[$index + 1].birthDate}}</div>
</div>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure that {{result[$index]}} and {{result[$index + 1]}} were working because for me they are not giving any output, but when I tried results instead of result its working fine.

Comment: that was my bad. Yes, it need to be results as pointed by @softvar and wZVang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/yk8phbc5/**

**JS**:

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.results = [
        {birthDate: '01/08/1982'},
        {birthDate: '11/08/1992'},
        {birthDate: '21/08/2002'},
        {birthDate: '31/08/2012'}
    ]
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">First: {{results[$index].birthDate}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Second: {{results[$index + 1].birthDate}}</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine but now the problem is, if i have odd no. of results i get the empty place holder "Second". Example, if i have 3 items in result, i get 2 rows, which is correct but for second row i get two columns when i should get only one column. The second column has only empty place holder. How to avoid this? Please take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yk8phbc5/1/

Comment: Yes @wZVanG, even for your answer i get the empty place holder. http://jsfiddle.net/yk8phbc5/1/. How to avoid this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

{{result[$index].birthDate}} must be {{**results**[$index].birthDate}}

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">{{results[$index].birthDate}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">{{results[$index + 1].birthDate}}</div>
</div>
```